# Hidden div doesn't show on hover via jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, hide, show, mousemove

I have a link and on the hover of this I'd like a div to be shown, all via jQuery, so to position the item with currentMousePos, but nothing happens.

I have tried to declare the class of the div that has to get the currentMousePos.

Here is the jQuery:

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
    $(".hidden-img").css('top', currentMousePos.y);
    $(".hidden-img").css('left', currentMousePos.x);
});
```

This is the CSS:

```
.list-item > div.hidden-img {
    display: none;
    height:300px;
    width:290px;
    margin-left:10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-20;
}

.list-item > a:hover + .list-item > div.hidden-img {
    display: block; 
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<li class="list-item">
    <a class="project-title">Text to hover</a>
     <div class="hidden-img">
      <img src='a-project-called/kremer/1.png'>
     </div>
</li>
```

I would like the div hidden-img to show on the hover of the class project-title.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are controlling the hiddenDiv's display mode through some rather complicated CSS selectors. While someone else may be able to offer you a CSS based soluton, I think a more elegant solution is using javascript to toggle the display mode instead.

By calling a function to toggle the hiddenDiv's display in the `onmouseenter` and `onmouseout` events of the controlling html element you can create the hover behavior you are looking for:

```js
//takes in an ID, finds element using that ID, then toggles that
//  element's display between block and none
function toggleHiddenDisplay(id){
  elem = document.getElementById(id)
  if(elem.style.display == 'none'){
    elem.style.display = 'block';
  }else elem.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div>
    <a onmouseenter=toggleHiddenDisplay('hiddenDiv')
       onmouseout=toggleHiddenDisplay('hiddenDiv')>
       Text to Hover
    </a>
    <div id="hiddenDiv" 
       style="color:white; background-color:red; display:none;">
       Hidden Content
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

So now you have two components:

1. Javascript/html-event based setup to toggle display mode on hover
2. Jquery script that sets an elements position based on the current cursor position.

These two can be integrated to give you the combination toggle+display at mouse behavior you want:

```js
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
    $(".hidden-img").css('top', currentMousePos.y);
    $(".hidden-img").css('left', currentMousePos.x);
});

function toggleHiddenDisplay(id){
  elem = document.getElementById(id)
  if(elem.style.display == 'none'){
    elem.style.display = 'block';
  }else elem.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.list-item > div.hidden-img {
    display: none;
    height:300px;
    width:290px;
    margin-left:10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-20;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list-item">
    <a class="project-title" onmouseenter=toggleHiddenDisplay("hoverDisplay") onmouseout=toggleHiddenDisplay("hoverDisplay")>Text to hover</a>
     <div class="hidden-img" id="hoverDisplay" style="display:none;">
      <img src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fe56d599fb9eeafdde6be4b369d51512?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'>
     </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Still, it doesn't work. The jQuery is called before my JS file, but the image won't show up on the hovering.
No errors showing on the console.

What is going on of wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is between the CSS, the JS, and the style="display:none;" of the HTML cause when I hover the display property stays as none, doesn't become "block"

Comment: The javascript function finds the elements by their ID, if you notice in the example I have added an ID to the hidden div. Did you add an ID to your hidden div? Alternatively you could change the javascript to find elements based on class name rather than ID. Either way you need to make sure the function you are calling on hover is actually getting the right element, whether by ID, class, or some other method.

Comment: Yes, I have the ID both in the getElementById, and in the hidden <div> tag.
Yet, the display property doesn't change from none to block. But it shows the position top and left changing as I move the mouse.
It's getting the right element but it won't change none to block.

Comment: And also the position of top and left are way far from where it should be, cause when I move the mouse it says 3/4000px on top and 1/2000px on left..
The div now actually appears, but not next to the pointer of the mouse..

Comment: So inside the `toggleHiddenDisplay` function if you add `console.log(elem)` on the line after the elem variable is populated it is properly printing the div you want to toggle the display on? And the function is being called on both `onmouseenter` and `onmouseout` events?

Comment: Now the display changes correctly..I had to switch the JS where now is if(elem.style.display == 'block' while before was 'none'
The problem still is that the hidden div isn't very close to the pointer..
I've added a / 2 after the currentMousePos.x and .y but still it's not attached to the pointer.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working. If you found the answer valuable and you have some time check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I've approved the answer, but still the position of the div isn't matching the pointer :(

Comment: Not sure what could be causing that issue without more detail about whats happening. Your function for setting the position to the pointer location seemed solid to me. See if you can figure it out by doing some debugging and console logging, if you cant figure anything you could consider opening another question for it.